# Create surface between irregular borders

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-printing

Is it possible to automatically create geometry to cap a very irregular large hole like the one in the pic below? There are overhangs and curves that are hard to see in this picture. Obviously the surface would have to consist of many different quads/tris because of the irregular and curved edge.
When I use F (fill tool), Blender creates just one weird face that connects to all the edges.

Thank you.

[image: I would like to create a surface between the selected edges]

Comment: With topology of this kind it can be more efficient to fill with any method (F can work just as well) and then enable Dyntopo, set it to Subdivide Collapse, choose adjacent amount of details and smoothen the surface untill the seam is not visible.

Comment: Thanks very much, Mr Zak. That seems to have done the job.

Comment: @MrZak, that looks useful—you should write up an answer!